# Retrieve top n records from Azure Table Storage with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to retrieve the Top n records from the Azure Table Storage using C#? I'm using .NET Core.

It would be great if I can get some references as well.

Please note that all my entities are stored using the Log Tail Pattern https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#log-tail-pattern

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Please include the code for how you (would) do it without the Top N condition. If you use Linq, see if adding `.Take(n)` works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Take()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery-1.take?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableQuery_1_Take_System_Nullable_System_Int32__) method when creating your [TableQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery-1?view=azure-dotnet):

```
TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>().Take(takeCount);
```

Or set the property [TakeCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery-1.takecount?view=azure-dotnet) to specify it:

```
TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>();
query.TakeCount = takeCount;
```

Comment: Setting only the `TakeCount` didn't work for me. I had to follow this example and check the count of entities retrieved. Anyway, this answer was the first step to a working solution :)

Comment: Hi @Simonca. were you able to retrieve top entity? Thankful for a solution.

Comment: Hi @DCodes! I've added an answer to this question with the solution we used, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing a concise and direct answer, with examples!

Answer (score 3):

What we did to get top entities of a table is as follows:

```
var query = new TableQuery<TEntity>()
            .Where(partitionFilter)
            .Take(limit);

return await ExecuteQuery(table, query);
```

Created the query and used `.Take(limit)` to specify how many entities we wanted.

```
 do
 {
      var seg = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<TEntity>(query, token);

      token = seg.ContinuationToken;

      items.AddRange(seg);
 } while (token != null && items.Count < query.TakeCount);
```

In `ExecuteQuery` method we counted how many records were retrieved from the table. This is how we did it and worked, I assume that in order to take top `n` entities the `limit` should be set to `n`.