# How to specify $top in Python Azure Tables query_entities?

Tags: python, azure-table-storage, azure-python-sdk

I want to filter on the PartitionKey, and get the top 1 record from the matches (using the default ordering specified by the RowKey values).

For filtering entities in a table, I'm using [`TableClient.query_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-data-tables/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-python#azure-data-tables-tableclient-query-entities). How can I add the $top parameter to the executed HTTP request?

`results_per_page = 1` does not limit the result count. I also tried these (found in random source codes) but they're ignored:

```
service.query_entities(
  query_filter = 'PartitionKey eq \'abc\'',
  parameters = {
    'top': 1
  }
)
```

```
from azure.data.tables._generated.models import QueryOptions
service.query_entities(
  query_filter = 'PartitionKey eq \'abc\'',
  query_options = QueryOptions(top = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Created two table entities to query the top entity that is BlueMarker in myTable.***

[image]

***You can get the Top row by http URL, via filtering your table with top parameter:***

- We can assign read/write permissions to the table and try accessing it via below given Url's:

  https://siliconstrg4.table.core.windows.net/myTable()?top=1
  https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Customers()?$top=10

[Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities)

***Run this command to get Top1 table entity per page :***

```
List_entities > Lists the entities in the table
```

```py
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="xxxxDefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<Accountkey>==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", table_name="<myTable>")
for entity in table_client.list_entities(results_per_page=1):
    print(entity)
```

[image]

***Top entity is returned in the output.***

[image]

- BlueMarker is the Top entity of the table.
- After you know the Topmost entity in your table, you can get that specific entity by filtering out its `PartitionKey and RowKey`  with `get_entity` as per the below code.

*If you need only a specific Top entity you can use the following code:*

```py
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="xxxxxEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<accountkey>==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", table_name="<myTable>")
task = table_client.get_entity( 'BlueMarker', 'RowID')
print(task)
```

***Output:***
[image]

***Only the top Entity BlueMarker is printed in the output by filtering with Partition Key and Row Key.***

You can use this code to get the `topmost entity` > by combining `get-entity and list_entity` command. Refer below:-

```py
from select import select
from tkinter import TOP
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="xxxxxEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName";AccountKey=<AccountKey>==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", table_name="<myTable>")
for entity in table_client.list_entities(results_per_page=1, select=["PartitionKey", "RowKey"] ):
    entity.task = table_client.get_entity( 'BlueMarker', 'RowID')
else:
    print(entity.task)
```

***Output:***

[image]

You will get the Topmost entity:
***Without else***-

```py
from select import select
from tkinter import TOP
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="xxxxxEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<AccountKey>==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", table_name="<myTable>")
for entity in table_client.list_entities(results_per_page=1, select=["PartitionKey", "RowKey"] ):
    entity.task = table_client.get_entity('BlueMarker', 'RowID')
print(entity.task)
```

***Output:***
[image]

**Note**:

1. Install `pip install azure-data-tables`
2. Get a connection string from
   `StorageAccounts -> AccessKeys` as shown below.
   [image]

*References:*
[MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities)
[Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-data-tables_12.4.1/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples/sample_query_tables.py)

Comment: This is not so useful and does not solve my problem. If I get a large list of the entities (a page), then I can just keep the first element and that is the topmost entity. There is no reason to query that one by exact PartitionKey-RowKey values. list_entities is not acceptable, since I have to filter on the PartitionKey, that is why I used query_entities. The result image of your first Python code clearly shows my problem: it returns more than one element, which is not needed for me. Your Python code does not show any example on how to use the $top parameter.

Comment: $top query is not yet supported in the Python azure-data-tables SDK, refer this [document](https://pypi.org/project/azure-data-tables/#querying-entities). As a workaround you can use Pandas head method to get the top entity Or try LINQ queries via C# refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/writing-linq-queries-against-the-table-service) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682489/retrieve-top-n-records-from-azure-table-storage-with-net-core). So, you can try with pandas head method and if that'll work, I can provide you the code.

Comment: That PyPi page does not indicate $top is not supported in the package. In fact, the module itself uses $top several times under the hood, based on their GitHub source codes, I just can't figure out how I should do it myself. Pandas has nothing to do here, that is a data processing module, calling .head() does not limit the downloaded dataset, and as I said I can already take the first element of a large raw downloaded list. I know it is possible in C#, but I have to use Python, that's why I asked about this module.

Comment: Please only answer to the exact question if you can. I'm not interested in anything else.